# How can I deal with unmounting fields and field-level validation with redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

So I am working with Redux-form to manage my form state. I want to have a simple expanding panel with fields inside so that the user is not overwhelmed with fields when the page is opened. The basic problem here is that when the fields are hidden, they are unmounted by the UI library I am using (react-md) so any field-level validation errors are discarded and the form will submit even when there are required or invalid fields. I know I could write a full validation function and skip the field-level validation alltogether, but I'd really rather not as my form is rather large and that would become cumbersome rather quickly.

I have tried having the fields mount and then un-mount with both `destroyOnUnmount` and `forceUnregisterOnUnmount` disabled, but it seems that the submission logic disregards errors for un-mounted fields even with those options disabled, so no dice. Any suggestions?

Edit: So, I tried wrapping each espansion panel in it's own form but I can't access my redux state in the onSubmit function of the parent form.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough situation. I was looking at the react-md module docs for the expansion panels and it looks like they might have a method that could solve the problem.

What they do is have each collapsable panel be its own form with it's own validations. When they finish a panel, they can press save for that panel and you can then save the state to some global set of form values to later pass on to the server.

This allows each panel to validate itself. To prevent them from prematurely submitting the form, you can write some simple JS logic that disables the overall submit button until all sub panels have been saved.

This would require a bit of lift but it would allow you to use the form level validations from redux-forms and also use the collapsible panel.

Good luck!

Comment: I like this idea, but do you think that there's any way for me to save the state in the redux-form state? I'd rather keep everything consolidated, but if it's not doable I can always just keep stuff in it's own separate variable in the redux store.

Comment: hmm, I can't think of a way around having it consolidated like that since you'll have to somehow collect the data from each form in some manner or the other. Keeping it as a separate variable in the redux store sounds like a good plan to me.

Comment: Hey, so after a little bit more work on this, I am running into the problem I thought I would. I can't access my redux state in the onSubmit function of my form, so there's not really any way for me to access the other forms's values. Any thoughts?

Comment: you should be able to access other forms with some custom selectors I would think. take a look reselect